# Ejecutar comandos de cordova sin sudo

Tags: ionic, cordova

soy un poco nuevo en Mac, quisiera saber como ejecuto comandos de cordova sin sudo, hay comandos que no necesitan sudo y por esa razón me causa muchos errores al compilar un proyecto de react o ionic, me ayudarían por favor con una solución

Comment: Utilizaste el instalador de node.js desde la página web o instalaste via terminal?

Comment: Desde la página web

Comment: Tienes que desinstalar e instalar via Homebrew. Te dejo el link de la respuesta: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34870503/ionic-npm-and-cordova-commands-all-require-sudo-to-work

Comment: Se me complica desinstalar node manualmente, habria otra forma? o alguna forma de que los comandos que son de cordova a través en ios no pida "sudo"